# Does sonarQube detects the unused methods called by reflection api

Tags: java, reflection, sonarqube

We are using sonarQube tool, which detects unused methods in the project. We have used java.lang.reflection api's to create/invoke the methods. The detected methods are really not used by reflection apis' or does it detects only the manual invocation of methods?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; no those method only invoked by reflexion will not be detected as used.

Longer answer : SonarQube relies on parsing and semantic analysis to be able to understand which methods is invoked where. Thismeans that only invoked methods will be detected as used. Please also consider that only private and protected methods can be flagged as unused as public method can be used in other project and as such cannot be detected as unused.